# Encaixar as columns header em um DGV, C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Existe alguma forma de encaixar as `columns` em um DGV de forma que não sobre o espaço (Segue a img como exemplo).
Ou Redimensionar o DGV para que ele recue ao tamanho necessário das `columns`? em tempo de execução.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando conexão direta ao `DB`portanto não visualizo as `columns`antes da execução.

Comment: Tenta mudar para `false` a propriedade [`RowsHeaderVisible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadersvisible(v=vs.110).aspx), assim: `dataGridView1.RowsHeaderVisible = false;`

Comment: @stderr as `RowHeaderVisible` já estão em `false` ..  o caso seria encontrar algum AutoSize pra ColumnsHeader se redimensionarem pro tamanho do DGV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você resolve isso acessando a propriedade `AutoSizeMode` de cada coluna. Por padrão, as colunas possuem `AutoSizeMode = NotSet`. Você precisará definir pelo menos uma coluna como `AutoSizeMode = Fill` em conjunto com a propriedade `FillWeight = 100`.

Exemplo:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].FillWeight = 100;
```

Abraço.

Comment: Perfeito amigo, Funcionou !